# Class overloaded operator '<' is not called when inserting shared pointer to set of that objects

Tags: c++, stl

Consider program below:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <memory>

class Boo
{
public:
    using ShPtr = std::shared_ptr<Boo>;

    bool operator < (const Boo& boo) const
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from operator";
        return true;
    }
};


int main(int, char*[])
{
    std::set<std::shared_ptr<Boo>> _container;

    _container.insert(Boo::ShPtr(new Boo()));

    return 0;
}
```

According to documentation for std::set:

> Internally, set containers keep all their elements sorted following
>   the criterion specified by its comparison object. The elements are
>   always inserted in its respective position following this ordering.

So I expect comparation object to be called every insert.

Comparation object is by default:

```
template<typename _Key, typename _Compare = std::less<_Key>,
       typename _Alloc = std::allocator<_Key> >
class set
{
 ...
}
```

So in that particulac case is:

```
template<typename _Sp>

struct _Sp_less : public binary_function<_Sp, _Sp, bool>
{
  bool
  operator()(const _Sp& __lhs, const _Sp& __rhs) const noexcept
  {
typedef typename _Sp::element_type element_type;
return std::less<element_type*>()(__lhs.get(), __rhs.get());
  }
};
```

Which idicates that comparasion is done by comparing object that shared pointer points to.

My question is: why in my program operator '<' of object of class Boo is not called?

Comment: Because you need to overload `<` for comparing `std::shared_ptr<Boo>`s.

Comment: @RichardCritten That's weird though because the normal `operator<` for `shared_ptr<T>` is to call std:less on shared_ptr.get() which would call the overloaded Boo operator so im not sure about that.

Comment: @SombreroChicken _"Note that the comparison operators for shared_ptr simply compare pointer values; the actual objects pointed to are not compared."_ source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp  So it compiles clean but only compares pointer values.

Comment: `operator <` is stripped out as unused when I compile this program (using VS2017). But it is not when I use it explicitely to compare two `Boo` automatic variables. This tends to confirm what @RichardCritten said above.

Comment: @RichardCritten is correct here.  Look at the snippet included.  It is comparing `__lhs.get()` and `__rhs.get()` which is comparing the raw pointers.  You can specify a custom comparator to the set constructor.

Comment: @RichardCritten it's up to you to write an actual answer. You got the point :)

Comment: @D.Shawley That's right, I missed that fact, it compares raw pointers in that case

Comment: You might be able to provide a free-function that compares shared pointers to `Boo`.  I don't think that a member would work here.

Comment: @RichardCritten Right, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Richard Critten noticed:

@SombreroChicken "Note that the comparison operators for shared_ptr simply compare pointer values; the actual objects pointed to are not compared." source: en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp So it compiles clean but only compares pointer values

Code below works as expected:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <memory>

template<typename _Sp>
struct CompShPtrByObj : std::_Sp_less<_Sp>
{
  bool
  operator()(const _Sp& __lhs, const _Sp& __rhs) const noexcept
  {
    typedef typename _Sp::element_type element_type;
    return std::less<element_type>()(*__lhs, *__rhs);
  }
};

class Boo
{
public:
    using ShPtr = std::shared_ptr<Boo>;

    bool operator < (const Boo& boo) const
    {
        std::cout << "Hello form boo";
        return true;
    }
};


int main(int, char*[])
{
    std::set<std::shared_ptr<Boo>, CompShPtrByObj<std::shared_ptr<Boo>>> _container;

    Boo::ShPtr sharedBoo(new Boo());
    Boo::ShPtr sharedBoo2(new Boo());

    _container.insert(sharedBoo);
    _container.insert(sharedBoo2);

    std::set<std::shared_ptr<Boo>, CompShPtrByObj<std::shared_ptr<Boo>>>::iterator iter = _container.find(sharedBoo);

    return 0;
}
```

But is that solution clear? Isn't that kind of changing default obvious way of working that would mislead anyone who use that container?